# Model-binding related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, model-binding, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework and I really like it, but there are still a lot of things to learn. I can't make the following case work.
I have two related entities: `Guest` and `SocialMedia`

The `CreateGuestViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class CreateGuestViewModel
{
    public CreateSocialViewModel SocialMedia { get; set; }
}
```

The View looks like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SocialMedia.Twitter"></label>
    <input asp-for="SocialMedia.Twitter" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter guest's twitter'" />
</div>
```

After I click the Save button, in the `GuestAppService.Create` method, the `SocialMedia` member is `null`.

```
[AutoMapTo(typeof(Guest))]
public class CreateGuestInput
{
    public CreateSocialMediaInput SocialMedia { get; set; }
}

[AutoMapTo(typeof(SocialMedia))]
public class CreateSocialMediaInput
{
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something. What do you think?

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

On html side you are using `CreateGuestViewModel` and `CreateSocialViewModel` as models. But on the application service you are binding `CreateGuestInput` and `CreateSocialMediaInput`. Models have to be same.